# ol3Cesium map not loading, giving error ''olcs is not defined"

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I am unable to load ol3cesium map in Ionic 2.

My index.html (code within body tag):

```
         <ion-app></ion-app>

         <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.16.0/build/ol.js"  
         <script src="../ol3-cesium-v1.17/ol3cesium.js"></script>
         <script src="../ol3-cesium-v1.17/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
```

My home.ts:

Inside constructor, below code is added --

```
        var view = new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            center: [-100, 35],
            zoom: 3
        });

        var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: 'http://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/wms',
                params: {
                    'LAYERS': 'ne:NE1_HR_LC_SR_W_DR'
                }
            })
        });
        var overlay = new ol.layer.Tile({
            opacity: 0.7,
            extent: [-124.74, 24.96, -66.96, 49.38],
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS(/** @type {olx.source.TileWMSOptions} */({
                url: 'http://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/wms',
                params: { 'LAYERS': 'topp:states', 'TILED': true },
                serverType: 'geoserver',
                crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
            }))
        });

        var ol2d = new ol.Map({
            layers: [layer, overlay],
            target: 'map2d',
            view: view
        });

        var ol3d = new olcs.OLCesium({ map: ol2d });
        var scene = ol3d.getCesiumScene();
        var terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
            url: '//assets.agi.com/stk-terrain/world'
        });
        ol3d.getCesiumScene().scene.terrainProvider = terrainProvider;

        ol3d.setEnabled(true);

    });
```

'map2d' is my div id in `home.html`.

I don't know why it is saying 'olcs is not defined' when running the project by `ionic serve --lab`. How can I resolve this JavaScript issue?

Comment: Pro tip: begging for urgency [is unacceptable here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495), and pretty much any volunteer-driven source of help on the web.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it. 
Actually i had to put cesium.js and ol3cesium inside www folder.